# How to convert "Saturday 9:00 PM" to date object?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Day of week and time are the only two information pieces that I have. How could I construct a valid date object (for current week) using `Date` or `moment.js`?

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
moment('Saturday 9:00 PM').format()
// "Invalid date"
```

Comment: in javascript, `Date` requires.... a Date.

Comment: And what saturday would that be, the next one, the previous one, a saturday in 1984 or maybe 2030 ?

Comment: You need to tell moment how to parse that.  http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: The question clearly states for the current week.

Comment: You could create a `Date` for today and then use `.getDay()` to figure out the day of the week for today and then figure out how many days you need to add (or subtract) to get one that matches the day of the week you want.

Comment: You can figure this out yourself. Please do so.

Comment: I agree with @MattBurland, the only question is whether or not you're only forward facing or if you want to include dates of the current week that have already passed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it wasn't googled first.

Comment: @MattBurland, see my other comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If natural language parsing is your primary concern, you might consider a library that specifically focuses on that, such as [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com/dates).

```
var dt = Date.create('Saturday 9:00 AM');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = 'Saturday 9:00 PM';
var days = [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
];

var parts = date.split(/\s/);
var day   = days.indexOf(parts[0]);
var hours = Number(parts[1].match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var mins  = Number(parts[1].match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM  = parts[2];
if(AMPM == "PM" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;

var d    = new Date();
var dday = d.getDay();

d.setDate(d.getDate() + (day - dday));
d.setHours(hours);
d.setMinutes(mins);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HgMmk/)

Answer (score 1):

The following parses the OP date string format, it uses Sunday as the first day of the week. The string can include seconds if the time is "09:32:23" and days like "Mon" or "Mo" rather than the full name and is not case sensitive ('mo' == 'Mo' == 'MO' etc.). It could also use *match* instead of *split* to handle the comma in "Monday, 09:00 AM".

```
// Turn a string like "Saturday 9:00 PM" into a date
// Assumes day in current week, Sunday is first day of week
var parseString = (function() {

    // constants
    var reAP  = /am$/i;
    var days  = {su:0,mo:1,tu:2,we:3,th:4,fr:5,sa:6};
    var reS = /[ :]+/;
    var reNum = /^[0-9]+$/;

    return function(s) {
      var b = s.split(reS);
      var now = new Date();
      var nowDay = now.getDay();
      var tgtDay = days[s.substr(0,2).toLowerCase()];
      now.setDate(now.getDate() - nowDay + tgtDay);
      now.setHours( (reAP.test(s)? 0 : 12) + +b[1], b[2], (reNum.test(b[3])? b[3]:0 ));
      return now; 
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by getting the week number with `moment().week()`, adding it to the string you already have (since saying *Saturday* by itself is ambiguous) and, as @Rocket Hazmat said, using moment.js's [parsing formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). Note that the solution below gives you this week's Saturday (which may not be *next* Saturday).

```
time_string = "Saturday 9:00 PM";
week_number = moment().week();                 // 19
time_string = time_string + ' ' + week_number; // now you have "Saturday 9:00 PM 19"
time = moment(time_string, "dddd h A w");      // guides parsing to read a day, hour, 
                                               //      am/pm and week number
```

Now that we're in week 19 of 2014, that will make `time`: `Sat May 10 2014 21:00:00 GMT -0000`

For the Saturday of last week (which may not be the same as *last Saturday*), the following, with the extra subtraction, yields: `Sat May 03 2014 21:00:00 GMT -0000`

```
time_string = "Saturday 9:00 PM";
week_number = moment().week();                 // 19
week_number = week_number - 1;                 // 18 = 19 - 1
time_string = time_string + ' ' + week_number; // now you have "Saturday 9:00 PM 18"
time = moment(time_string, "dddd h A w");      // guides parsing to read a day, hour, 
                                               //     am/pm and week number
```

Note that if you do not specify a week number, it defaults to `1` and it gives you a date in January.